# Meteor - prevent a template from rerendering each time {{#if}} is reevaluated

Tags: javascript, meteor

Here's what I'm trying to do. If the current Photo object (which we have via the photoId variable) has a URL property, show it as an `img`. If not, show a spinner:

```
{{#if photoUrl photoId}}
  <img src="{{photoUrl photoId}}"/>
{{else}}
  {{> spinner}}
{{/if}}
```

The helper method:

```
photoUrl: function (photoId) {
  var photo = Photos.findOne(photoId);
  if (photo && photo.croppedUrl)
    return photo.croppedUrl;
}
```

This works fine for old posts. But just-posted posts, whose photos are still uploading, rerender this template several times in the first couple seconds. Which would be OK if the content were static, but the spinner is spinning, and each rerender makes it start over.

My hunch is that the template was rerendering because my uploading library ([collectionFS](https://github.com/CollectionFS/Meteor-CollectionFS)) is making changes to the new `Photo` object, and each time that happens, Meteor reevaluates `photoUrl`, because it has that object as a dependency (right?). Wrapping the helper body in `Meteor.nonreactive`, for example, fixes the immediate problem (though it creates others).

I would've assumed Meteor would only rerender templates after an actual change to an `{{#if}}` condition, but it seems like it rerenders every time the condition is reevaulated, regardless of the result.

Is there a way to prevent unnecessary (i.e. same value of `{{#if}}` condition) rerendering? Or must I find a way to get the photo URL without directly referencing the `Photo` object?

Answer (score 0):

You most likely wouldn't have to do this in future versions of Meteor.

In the current version, if the {{if}} value doesn't change you shouldn't have a re-render. The re-render is probably caused by something else on the page that would cause the entire template to re-render. Perhaps you are using something from the collection somewhere else in the template? The template has a check: only if the HTML is different would the template be re-rendered.

To fix this you would wrap something that changes in an `{{#isolate}}` .. `{{/isolate}}` block. This will isolate everything inside the block from changes outside of it.

So the changes would re-render and patch out everything in the isolate block instead of re-rendering the entire template.

Comment: I've tried using `isolate` (and also `constant`) blocks all over the template in various ways, and it really seems like the reactivity/rerenders are coming from the `if` block itself.

Comment: Try putting a `console.log` in to see what changes in photoUrl helper. The idea of isolate is not to stop the re-rendering but to isolate it from the rest of the template. To stop it re-rendering you need to see what is causing it to change, if it is changing (which it should be as its re-rendering).

Answer (score 0):

I have similar trouble too. There are several ways to solve problem, I think.

1. try to use find instead of findOne, such as
   `{{#each photoes}}{{#if croppedUrl}}...{{/each}}`
2. try to seperate new item and old item, old item show using these code and new item showing a spin directly.
3. try to use constant, and show everything you need in js code in rendered

Hopes it helps